# How can I set an envariable for all apps *permanently* in MacOS?

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I would like to set an envariable that will be referenced by an application that's ***not*** invoked via the command line, but rather by double-clicking its icon somewhere. The only way I know to do this is with

```
launchctl setenv VARIABLE value
```

which does the job, but whose effect terminates on reboot. Is there any way I can get this effect permanently, i.e., so that people don't have to remember to do it again whenever the machine reboots?

(In days of yore I could get the effect I need by putting the above statement in ~/launchd.conf, but that feature "was removed for security considerations". And note that it's not enough to put a `launchctl` command in .bashrc or the like, because my target users may never start a shell.)

Comment: I don't know if this will actually work since I haven't tried it on macOS but in theory you can use PAM (pluggable authentication modules) to do this. See `man pam_env` and `man pam.conf`.